# Get content type of chatMessageHostedContent

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

is there any way to retrieve the content type of chatMessageHostedContent?

Via graphClient.Chats["id"].Messages["id"].HostedContents["id"].Content.Request().GetAsync() I get the stream, but I don't know what kind of file it is.
If I send the request manually via the GraphServiceClient's HttpProvider, then I get the content type but have to handle decoding...

Is there a better/simpler solution here?

Comment: Really, no one has any ideas?
How do you read and store the hosted content of a chat message?

Comment: Did you try fetching the hostedContent first? 
await graphClient.Chats["{chat-id}"].Messages["{chatMessage-id}"].HostedContents["{chatMessageHostedContent-id}"]
 .Request()
 .GetAsync();
Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessagehostedcontent-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-1-get-hosted-content-for-message-in-a-chat

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. But despite the documentation I don't get the ContentType/ContentBytes for code snipped or embedded image. There are always set to null.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT: Did you try the provided code? Do you get ContentType/ContentBytes?

Comment: Hi, we tried with the provided code and also faced the same issue, did not get the ContentType/ContentBytes. This seems like a bug and we have raised it with concerned team.

Comment: @Prithvi-MSFT: Thanks for your information. How can I find out when the error is fixed?

Comment: @Anne - We have confirmed with engineering team and they said that this is intended since content can be GBs in size. You can use $value to stream while using Graph API.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft Ok, but actually my problem is that ContentType is null and this property shouldn't be so large. Are there any plans to fix this?