# Size limit on chatMessageHostedContent content bytes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Is there any size limit on the contentBytes Microsoft Graph API v1 chatMessageHostedContent? I am figuring out how to download hosted content, given that I am constrained with a ~8mb content download size limit.

One of the comments in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68466933/get-content-type-of-chatmessagehostedcontent) says that contentBytes can be in GBs. If so, what is the way to upload such a huge hosted content. I was able to send only around 3mb of hosted content bytes along with the [SendMessage API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-4).

Comment: Graph API does not allow greater than 4MB payloads.

Comment: The SendMessage post API doesn't allow content bytes to be more than 4 mb. But I have verified that adding an inline image much greater than 4 mb in size via chat UI works. The max possible size of hosted content should be documented IMO

Answer (score 0):

According to [this discussion](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/15334), while posting the maximum size is 4 MB. Generally, the size should not exceed 3 GB and it's better to split up the files.

Comment: How is 3GB size possible if 4mb is the limit while posting? Is there any other way to create hosted content